# How to reset the numbering when adding another block level element like numbered list

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Editor]

When I add new numbered list in flutter quill, the number is continued from previous code block line number like in that picture. How do I make sure when entering a new block level like numbering list is reset from one?

I try to find about resetting line number but there is no such solution.